# MOSFET Switching Loss Formula

Tags: voltage, mosfet, current, dc-dc-converter, boost

I'm trying to calculate the switching loss of the MOSFET which is used for a DC-DC Boost converter.
Input Voltage : 9V-16V

Output Voltage : 30V

Output Current : 0.3A.

Switching Freq : 455kHz

Based on this [App Note][1] the Switching loss formula is given on page 3, equation 4.

[image]

If I calculate the switching loss based on the above formula, it comes to around 14W.

In this [Article](https://www.powerelectronicsnews.com/the-dc-dc-boost-converter-part-2-power-supply-design-tutorial-section-5-2/), the formula for calculating the switching loss is different.

[image]

Which one is the correct formula and could you explain the reason for 2 different formulas?

[1]: https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slyt664/slyt664.pdf?ts=1617773788537&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F#:~:text=MOSFET%20switching%20losses%20are%20a,as%20shown%20by%20Equation%204.&text=where%20VIN%20%3D%20VDS%20(drain%2D,IG%20is%20the%20gate%20current

Comment: these formulas may well be identical because each of GS2 and GD capacitances is charged by a current \$I_G/2\$

Comment: Switching frequency 455 kHz ... that'll make you popular!

Comment: I'm unable to understand. And why 455kHz would make me popular/

Comment: That’s the IF channel for AM radios , some interference is possible nearby.

Comment: Also Q=CV and Ig =Vgs/Rg peak during tR,tF so peak power is something like Vg^2/Rg * C * 2f  (?) for C=Ciss which is related to Cgd,Cgs or Qgd,Qgs

Comment: By looking a Figure of Merit calculations in a spreadsheet, I used D-K’s data downloaded into a cvs file to find the lowest RdsOn/Ciss and RdsOn/Coss ratio that meets all other filtered requirements. This means lowest Vgs and Tr/f for a past e load. But a boost regulator with ZVS or zero valley switching resonant conversion is more efficient (98% is possible vs <&# %

Comment: Oops I meant lowest RdsOn * C = T  product. Another brain fart, I better finish 150 ft of flooring with corner round and Brad nail gun